# Check if a string contains another string from different Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes with different columns and size.

The first one has some columns and one of them is a string field (column 1). The second dataframe has 2 columns, one is a string field (column 4) with 2 words separated by comma and another is a integer field (column 5).

I need to verify that column 1 in Dataframe 1 has the words in column 4 Dataframe 2 and fill in Dataframe 1 with the corresponding information in dataframe 2.

Example:

```
df1
    column 1                                column 2          column 3
0   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample2         a                 f
1   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample5         b                 g
2   bla bla sample3 bla bla sample4         c                 h
3   bla bla sample8 bla bla sample7         d                 i
4   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample2         e                 j

 df2
    column 4                       column 5
0   ('sample1', 'sample2'),        50
1   ('sample3', 'sample4'),        35 
2   ('sample1', 'sample5')         18
```

I need the output:

```
Output:
df1
    column 1                               column 2  column 3  column 4                     column 5
0   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample2        a         f         ('sample1', 'sample2')     50
1   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample5        b         g         ('sample1', 'sample5')     18
2   bla bla sample3 bla bla sample4        c         h         ('sample3', 'sample4')     35
3   bla bla sample8 bla bla sample7        d         i         NaN        
4   bla bla sample1 bla bla sample2        e         j         ('sample1', 'sample2')     50
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two questions. First, is column 4 a string separated by commas `'sample1, sample2'` as you indicate in the question, or a tuple of two strings, as you have in your sample. Second, is the requirement that both strings be found in column1?

Comment: I can only think of O(n,m) solution ..

Comment: @ALollz First - Sorry, it's a tuple of two strings. Second - Yes, both strings be found in column 1.

Comment: Last question. What happens when `column 1` has sample 1, sample 2 and sample 5? Should the output have both possible combinations (so it would increase by one row) or do we take only one of the matches?

Comment: @ALollz 
when column 1 has more than one combination, column 4 must have all combinations and add the value of column 5.

Example: 
Output - Df1:
Column 1 - bla bla sample1 bla sample2 bla sample5
Column 4 - sample1, sample2, sample5
Column 5 - 68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't guarantee this will be particularly fast, but it gets the job done. We'll use `set` logic to check for matches. We have to jump through some hoops so that we can store a list of tuples of the matches. I don't think this is a particularly good idea.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1['setc'] = df1['column 1'].str.split().apply(set)
# Initialize so addition works
df1['column 4'] = [[] for i in range(len(df1))]
df1['column 5'] = 0

for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    m = (df1.setc.values & set(row['column 4'])) == set(row['column 4'])
    df1.loc[m, 'column 4'] += pd.Series([[row['column 4']] for x in range(len(m))])[m]
    df1.loc[m, 'column 5'] += row['column 5']

df1 = df1.drop(columns='setc')
# NaN where nothing matched
df1.loc[df1['column 4'].str.len().eq(0), ['column 4', 'column 5']] = np.NaN
```

#### Output:

```
                          column 1 column 2 column 3                                  column 4  column 5
0  bla bla sample1 sample5 sample2        a        f  [(sample1, sample2), (sample1, sample5)]      68.0
1  bla bla sample1 bla bla sample5        b        g                      [(sample1, sample5)]      18.0
2  bla bla sample3 bla bla sample4        c        h                      [(sample3, sample4)]      35.0
3  bla bla sample8 bla bla sample7        d        i                                       NaN       NaN
4  bla bla sample1 bla bla sample2        e        j                      [(sample1, sample2)]      50.0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!